# Mysql query returning empty object

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql package in nodeJS to query my result but having trouble in retrieving data

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'PASSWORD',
database : 'ambuCenter'
});
var data;
function do_queries(callback){
    connection.connect();
    connection.query(
        "SELECT * FROM customers",
        function(err,result,fields){
            if (err) return callback(err,null);
            callback(err,result);
        }
    );
connection.end();
}

function request_handler(){
do_queries(
    function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        data = JSON.stringify(result);
        data = JSON.parse(data); 
        console.log(data);
    }
);
}
request_handler();
console.log(data);
```

first console.log(data) is returning an object,
but the one in the end is returning undefined value

```
Manishs-MacBook-Air:Models manishbaghel$ node db_model.js 
undefined
[ { id: 1, name: 'John', address: 'Highway 71' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Peter', address: 'Lowstreet 4' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Amy', address: 'Apple st 652' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Hannah', address: 'Mountain 21' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Michael', address: 'Valley 345' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Sandy', address: 'Ocean blvd 2' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Betty', address: 'Green Grass 1' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Richard', address: 'Sky st 331' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Susan', address: 'One way 98' },
]
```

Comment: cause when you define `data` it has been set to type `undefined`. and rest is the `async` nature of nodejs

Comment: Then how should I retrieve the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `callback` argument (function) that is passed to `do_queries` executes in a separate thread (i.e. asynchronously). So, this is what happens:

1. Thread 1 calls `do_queries`, which in turn spawns a new thread (say Thread 2)
2. Thread 1 calls `request_handler`
3. Thread 1 calls `console.log`
4. Thread 2 makes db call and returns to callback function

The order will not be exactly the same, however, as both the operations are executed independent of each other and asynchronously, there is no guarantee that `data` will have any value assigned before last `console.log` is called. Hence, you get `undefined`.

Also, it's not recommended to update/change the global variables from callback function so you probably need to change the logic and move the updates to callback functions.

Comment: Now, what would you suggest to retrieve the data

Comment: You need to write the logic inside the callback function for `do_queries`. Why do you need to access it from outside?